# How to get Scala to handle large numbers

Tags: python, scala, bigint

I have a function  in Python which I'm trying to convert to Scala:

Python:

```
def pseudoRandom(value):
  loops = (value & 0x7F) + 21
  for index in range(loops):
    value += ((value * 7) ^ (value << 15)) + 8 * index - (value >> 5)
    value &= ((1 << 64) - 1)
  return value
```

In Scala I have defined it as follows:

```
def pseudoRandom(value: Long): Long = {
  val loops = (value & 0x7F) + 21L
  var v = value
  (0L to loops).foreach { index =>
    v += ((v * 7) ^ (v << 15)) + 8 * index - (v >> 5)
    v &= ((1 << 64) -1)
  }
  v
}
```

Presumably this fails due to overflows but I'm not sure how to fix it.  I've tried using BigInt as follows:

```
def pseudoRandom(value: Long): BigInt = {
  val loops = (value & 0x7F) + 21L
  var v = BigInt(value)
  (0L to loops).foreach { index =>
    v += ((v * 7) ^ (v << 15)) + 8 * index - (v >> 5)
    v &= ((1 << 64) -1)
  }
  v
}
```

This also fails.

Behaviour I would expect (based on python code):

```
Input      Output
1          7979149037415411353
2          934307080801911839
3          9329215801069440317
```

Actual output from my scala code

```
Input      Output
1          0
2          0
3          0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
def pseudoRandom(value: Long): BigInt = {
  val loops = (value & 0x7F).toInt + 21
  val mask = (BigInt(1) << 64) - 1
  var v = BigInt(value)
  for (i <- 0 until loops) {
    v += ((v * 7) ^ (v << 15)) + 8 * i - (v >> 5)
    v &= mask
  }
  v
}
```

Unsorted enumeration of problems with your code:

- As soon as you truncate to `& 0x7F`, it's definitely a small int, not a long
- `range(n)` corresponds to `0 until n`, not `0 to n`
- `1 << 64` doesn't give you anything sane, define a `BigInt` mask once instead
- `foreach` is non-idiomatic, use simple `for`-loop sugar for that.

Output for first ten positive integers:

```
7979149037415411353
934307080801911839
9329215801069440317
8332103895783241284
1972840215733196111
9936661750801020912
9568736274889204650
13195389261695658308
3299225817465251241
3456601764545139813
```

The zeros appear because `(1 << 64) - 1 = 0`

Comment: Brilliant :) Scala is pretty new to me, mix that with bit wise logic and it has me stumped lol